# How to find if a specific date is between two different row dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a query that can identify if the EndDate lies between the first PlanTerminationDate and the second PlanEffectiveDate of a particular ID.

```
+----+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| ID | PlanEffectiveDate | PlanTerminationDate | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 11 | 2/9/2019          | 11/18/2020          | 12/26/2019 | 11/26/2020 |
| 11 | 1/7/2021          | 1/25/2021           | 12/26/2019 | 11/26/2020 |
| 12 | 10/9/2018         | 4/13/2020           | 6/5/2019   | 5/6/2020   |
| 12 | 6/19/2020         | 9/16/2020           | 6/5/2019   | 5/6/2020   |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

For example: For ID 11, the EndDate 11/26/2020 lies between 11/18/2020 and 1/7/2021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which DB are you on?
Also, are you always going to have 2 rows per ID?
If yes, you could just do something like this -

```
select sub_qry.id, <other columns you need>,
case when end_date between min_pln_term and max_pln_eff then 'Yes' else 'No' end as your_check_flag
from (
select id,
min(PlanTerminationDate) as min_pln_term,
max(PlanEffectiveDate) as max_pln_eff,
EndDate as end_date
from your_table
group by id, EndDate ) sub_qry
```

If not, you'll have to try to use `LEAD` to get the subsequent start date for each termination date and then do a check on top of it.

```
select id, 
PlanEffectiveDate, 
PlanTerminationDate, 
lead(PlanEffectiveDate, 1) over (partition by id order by PlanEffectiveDate) as next_plan_eff_date,
EndDate
from your_table
```

Using the above as a sub query, you could just do -

```
select id, PlanEffectiveDate, PlanTerminationDate, next_plan_eff_date, end_date,
case when end_date between PlanTerminationDate and next_plan_eff_date then 'Yes' else 'No' end as your_check_flag
from above_sub_query
```

Another thing not clear is if you're always going to have one EndDate per ID. Assuming it is, the above query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using self join.The query can be like this:-

select t1.columnname,......,from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t1.endate>=t1.Planterminationdate and t1.enddate<=t2.Planeffectivedate

In the place of t1.columnname write the columnnames you need and change the tablename with the name of the table.

Comment: Yes, I did try the joins but since I am matching the dates from different rows, it does not return any records.